# Zombies: if magic kept them "living" or at least conscious, what would they experience as they rotted?

Tags: biology, magic, zombies, death

Instead of being spread by a virus or the temporary effects of a voodoo-induced trance or paralysis, zombies are created by a magical curse that causes the person to rot while remaining relatively cognitively present until they reach an advanced state of decay (a state in which I imagine they'd basically look and act like the zombies on The Walking Dead - they're still conscious but are either too cognitively decayed or too numb from trauma to do much besides bumble around and groan or just be dead).

Granted, the journey from fresh and mostly-intact to rotting and less-intact is not a smooth journey and their cognitive abilities will not be as sharp on day 28 as they would be on day 1, but through their gross journey of decay they would generally be cognitively present enough to think "This sucks."

So, my question is essentially "What would it feel like to be mentally conscious while your body rotted?" E.g. Would chunks of you fall apart like in comical presentations of zombies? Would your senses fade away? Would you experience pain or would your ability to feel pain go away after a few days? Etc.

Factors/other questions you could consider:

- What if magic kept the body animated while they rotted? What would it be like to experience their symptoms while still capable of moving? Maybe they try to stand up to make a coffee and their leg (painlessly?) breaks, or maybe they catch a knot brushing their hair and rip a chunk of hair and scalp off, or maybe this action causes most of their head and face skin to slide off!
- Could magic make it so parts of their body decay slower than others? For example, could things such as their heart, brain, or other organs remain somewhat functional while their skin, muscle, bone, or other systems become excessively unhealthy? (I understand a functioning heart obviously prevents cell death so I'm not totally sure how this specifically might work but there's magic involved so everything is slightly flexible - maybe the curse causes blood to circulate through some parts of the body and not others)
- Bonus points if some kind of timeline is loosely included

Comment: This question is just too close to Necrotizing Fasciitis https://www.cdc.gov/groupastrep/diseases-public/necrotizing-fasciitis.html

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond True, the symptoms could be similar to this and forms of necrosis and gangrene, but I'm not sure those conditions are similar enough. Most importantly, reading about these conditions online doesn't help me learn what it might be like to be conscious while my body rotted past the point of normal function. I'm talking possibly experiencing things only a dead body would normally experience, not just experiencing ulcers and nausea etc. So I'm not sure these pages fully answer my question as the symptoms they describe are experienced by people who are still functionally alive.

Comment: "*Could magic make it so*" Yes. No. Maybe. Since magic doesn't actually exist, there is no answer other than: "Pick any that applies to *your* type of magic system.". We don't know what that is - you've not explained it. If you want us to *come up* with magic, then sure - the answer is "Yes, the magic system I just made up, can solve this one thing that caused me to make up the magic for".

Comment: I suggest watching Return of the Living Dead. When questioned about why zombies eat brains, a captive zombie says that eating brains helps with the pain of being dead. Based on this highly scientific documentary film, I'd say we have proof that being dead hurts and consuming brains has at least some pain reducing properties for someone who is dead.

Comment: @VLAZ Oops. I should’ve reworded that part of my “factors/other questions” section. That part of my post was less important to me and more of just a “fun other things to consider if you want” part so I didn’t put enough thought into it.

Comment: @EscapedLunatic Ha, that’s my favourite zombie movie, and I actually mimic that idea quite closely… but didn’t want to go into details and share the specific traits of my zombies for creative ownership purposes.

Comment: You are missing my point, These diseases EXACTLY describe what a person goes through when the disease is untreated and they indeed rot away, while thy are fully conscious. ALS is the same only different - the body stops working over time. Add phantom limb syndrome to the list. You are talking about real diseases, real experiences, do not reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 5):

## Do not google for images of this if you are faint of heart

> So, my question is essentially "What would it feel like to be mentally conscious while your body rotted?"

You would feel like a person with a case of opioids abuse, but involving a very specific drug that is 10x more potent than morphine.

What you describe in the question kind of exists in the real world, without the magic component. There is this sedative called [desomorphine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desomorphine). It is as addictive as most opioids and the version people buy on the streets (called **krokodil**, the "zombie drug", or the "flesh eating drug") has impurities which make it more toxic. According to the link:

> Gangrene, phlebitis, thrombosis (blood clots), pneumonia, meningitis, septicaemia (blood infection), osteomyelitis (bone infection), liver and kidney damage, brain damage (...) are common serious adverse health effects observed among users of krokodil. Sometimes, the user will miss the vein when injecting the desomorphine, creating an abscess and causing death of the flesh surrounding the entry-point.

Some pictures of addicts show their arms or legs so rotten that you can see their bones. Again, don't google it.if you can't handle it.

And since this is a potent analgesic, users will be quite numb, apathetic and not in their best shape mentally for long spans throughout their days as long as the addiction lasts. But they won't be completely mindless, even as flesh falls off of their limbs. They may also have episodes of anger and rage, specially when withdrawal symptoms hit. This is as close to Holywood zombies as real life gets.

Comment: This does not sound like something I would enjoy. You get all the drawbacks of being a zombie but none of the superpowers.

Comment: @Daron Yes, I would not recommend it. Try to avoid becoming a non-superpowered zombie. If at all possible, of course.

Answer (score 4):

### Actually, we have done a lot of research on this - Look at Acute Radiation Syndrome.

Although you tag Magic, the zombies still experience the real world, and for the data of what you describe you need look no further than [Acute Radiation Syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_radiation_syndrome).

One could argue that your zombies are in fact humans that have been given a short burst of a very large dose of radiation, starting at around 0.7 Grays but can go up to beyond 30. This dose is enough to 'kill' you.

In essence, your immune system is destroyed. What happens next is the stuff of horror movies, but has been carefully scientifically studied intently when it occurs, for example at the [Nuclear Disaster at Chernobyl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernobyl_disaster), or the effects of the [Atomic Bomb at Hiroshima](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_bombings_of_Hiroshima_and_Nagasaki).

Without an immune system, it is arguable if you really are alive as we constantly live in a soup of bacteria and viruses and even have them inside us when we live, which our immune system constantly fights. Without it, all resident pathogens already within our body, and external ones, can now eat without hindrance starting with your gastrointestinal system, followed by the blood and other internal organs.

So the following experiences occur, all the while you are 'conscious':

1. Hemotopoietic: No / low white blood cells causes aplastic anaemia, and red blood cell count also, basically your blood cannot repair any wounds or effectively deliver any immune response, meaning weakness, scarring, fatigue and Leukopenia. This also prevents skin cell repair and hair follicle adherence, and depending on dose [burns on the skin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_burn), and [hair falling out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hair_loss), within a few hours.
2. Gastrointestinal Tract: Immediate internal bleeding throughout the entire tract, causing nausea, diarrhea vomiting, abdominal pain, and loss of appetite.
3. Neurovascular: This process also affects brain function, as pathogens consume your brain and loss of body functions also cause High fever, Dizziness and disorientation, Headache and Shock.

After the above, your major body organs start to fail, causing skin cells to detach, hair connections to fail, hearts to become arrhythmic, lungs to be scarred, and complete body function failure is unfortunately assured.

In terms of timeline, for an acute dose of more than 30 Grays:

- Less than 10 minutes: Nausea and Vomiting
- Less than 1 hour: Diarrhea, Headache and Fever, Tremors, Seizures
- Less than 48 hours: Fever, Dizziness, Disorienation, Hypotension, Hemorrhage, skin lesions and hair follicle detachment
- 48 hours: Actual shutdown of a major organ, such as the heart, lungs or brain, causing body failure. (in your case, the zombie would not be able to do useful work at this point).

There is data available on this process in many resources - as those that deal with radiation must be aware of symptoms and dangers. Your zombies would not be enjoying their experience, as Acute Radiation Sickness is considered one of the most painful and inexorable experiences you would hope never to have.

Comment: Now I wonder what the ghouls in the Fallout universe feel like.

Comment: @Joachim Yes, being eaten from the inside out while awake is not fun at all.

Answer (score 2):

### Chilblains, itches and phantom pain

The zombie will ignore it, at first. The zombie is used to feel the persistent itch of rotting, because it is dead and already rotting. When it gets worse however, the zombie will start to loose toes, fingers and eventually, entire limbs.

**Keep your house clean**

If you want to keep your loved ones alive as zombies, make sure your house stays clean. House flies and fungus thrive on zombies and will accelerate the rotting.

**Make sure you cut its nails**

Scratching will make things worse. The itch will make zombies scratch themselves to the bone. It will be a mess and you won't like the smell. Best way to prevent that is to cut its nails regularly.

**Loosing body parts**

When the rotting proceeds, your zombie could start loosing body parts. It remembers having legs and arms and now they are gone. Phantom pain kicks in, which is far worse than the itching.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phantom_pain

When this happens, it's time for your zombie to return to the grave, to reinforce its life cycle. Kill your darlings, bury your zombie remains and let magic do its work.